# Prevent automatic escaping of backslash in strings by autopep8 in VS Code Python scripts

Tags: python, regex, string, visual-studio-code, autopep8

I have VS Code set up with the Python plugin and autopep8. My relevant settings are:

```
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",   
    "editor.formatOnSave: true,
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args":[
        "--agressive"
    ]
}
```

I like most of what this accomplishes with regards to auto-formatting (cutting line length, replacing the odd thing here or there) but there is one feature that is really bugging me.

I am working with pySpark and have a `regexp_replace` function set up as

```
df = df.withColumn('NewCol', regexp_replace(col('OldCol'), '\W', ' ')
```

When I save the file, every time, the autoformatter replaces `'\W'` with `'\\W'`. I can see why its doing it (normally, a single backslash in a string is a mistakenly un-escaped character), but in this instance, I need it to stop. Are there any arguments I can pass which ignore just this case? I dont mind it never escaping a backslash again. But I would rather not turn off `--agressive` correction for all the other things it achieves.

Comment: You just need to get accustomed to use *raw* string literals.

Comment: Clearly I do! Raw strings was the answer I was looking for. They never occurred to me at the time and I think I misunderstood their purpose when I was reading about them earlier (somehow I read that raw strings act like all special characters are automatically escaped - displaying one slash but behaving like there are 2 - when they do the opposite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off this setting is a **bad idea**.

Invalid escape sequences [are depreciated as of Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#deprecated-python-behavior) and will eventually cause a `SyntaxError`. Even if you currently have no intention of upgrading what Python version you're using, using invalid escape sequences will limit the portability of your code.

Instead, use raw strings:

```py
df = df.withColumn('NewCol', regexp_replace(col('OldCol'), r'\W', ' ')
```

---

But, if you *really* want to disable this setting, you can use the `--ignore` flag with `W605`, as described [here](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/).

```json
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",   
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args":[
        "--aggressive",
        "--ignore W605"
    ]
}
```

As described in the previous link, issue code `W605` corresponds to "Fix invalid escape sequence 'x'".

Comment: I totally misunderstood raw strings. It was the solution I was looking for. I dislike disabling things with auto formatters and linters because those warnings are there for a reason. Sometimes its unavoidable, and I had to disable an import warning with pylint which just kept throwing up issues with a correct absolute import path, and I may have to do the same for a different import warning, because VS Code runs my code and unit tests 100% fine, but pylint keeps throwing errors saying that my pyspark install has no sql.function module (which it does, because the program runs). Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help :)